# ImportError: No module named 'generate_xml'

Tags: python, importerror, yolo

I am trying to create a project on real time vehicle classification using yolo model. When I am trying to annotate the vehicle images this error pops up:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "train.py", line 5, in <module>

    from generate_xml import write_xml

ImportError: No module named 'generate_xml'
```

Source which I've used to train can be found [here](https://github.com/markjay4k/YOLO-series/blob/master/part6%20-%20draw_box_py36.py).

Comment: There is generate_xml module deployed in project. Please implement all files in project...

https://github.com/markjay4k/YOLO-series

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just rename `part7 - generate_xml.py` to `generate_xml.py` and make sure it's in the same location your script is running from